# JQuery/JS question: how can I change "x" everytime a bind is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the variable `x` to 3 every time the window gets resized.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var x = $("#display_piece_big_frame").offset().left;

    $(window).bind("resize", function()
    {
        x = 300;
    });
});
```

*Note: `x` cannot be put outside the `document.ready` function because it uses jQuery.*

Comment: what's wrong with the code you posted? Is it giving an error?

Comment: Show me some code accessing the _X_ variable. Is that code inside the ready-function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the variable x outside the ready function. Put it in the global scope, or in an object in the global scope.

```
var x = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).bind('resize', function() { x = 3; });
});
```

Comment: "x" cannot be put outside the document.ready function because it uses JQUERY.

Comment: put x without assigning value and assign value inside document ready